# Batch script does not execute properly when launched automatically

Tags: batch-file, installation, privileges

I've an issue that seems a privilege issue but i really do not understand what is happening.

This is my installation script :

```
 ...some command...
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\installutil C:\Programmi\ProgDir\ProgService.exe >> log.txt

 ping 127.0.0.1 -n 5 > null
 REG DELETE "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v Shell /f
 ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 > null
 REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v Shell /t REG_SZ /d C:\Programmi\ProgDir\ProgName.exe /f
```

I try this script using installation wizard (created by winrar) and manually , in both cases i give to the script admin privilege; to prove this the service is installed successfully (it require administration privilege, so the script has these privileges as expected) but the registry is not affected if the script is launched by the wizard.

Can anybody explain to me what is happening ?
Thanks in advance (and sorry for my poor english)

Comment: You really ask us how to replace `Explorer.exe` started after logon as Windows desktop by your application? In other words you want help on malware installation? Sorry, no support from us.

Comment: I need to release an installer for a sofware that work on some workstation (XP at start, but now seven) between user and plc.
The user can not access to desktop or it could change the plc setting, so i need to hide the standard shell.
The above script work well on xp but doen't on seven, my question is why.
Ps i suppose there are better way to instal a rootkit than change shell form a batch script..